# Spigot PlayerInteractEntityEvent

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am using Spigot 1.11.2.

I have this simple code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractEntity (PlayerInteractEntityEvent event) {
    if (entity instanceof AbstractHorse) {
        event.setCancelled(true);

        AbstractHorse horse = (AbstractHorse) event.getRightClicked();
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        player.sendMessage(horse.getName());
    }
}
```

What it's supposed to do is if I right-click a horse, I should get its name but I shouldn't ride it, because of the `event.setCancelled(true)`. It works as expected, but the problem is that when I right-click a horse, the game turns my view around (my player's yaw) to some number that is not consistent. Yet I don't want to turn around; I still want my player to be looking at where I was looking at (at the horse in this case) after I right-click the horse.

I tried some methods, like saving my pitch and yaw then setting it again after cancelling the event:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractEntity (PlayerInteractEntityEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    float pitch = player.getLocation().getPitch();
    float yaw = player.getLocation().getYaw();

    if (entity instanceof AbstractHorse) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
        player.getLocation().setPitch(pitch);
        player.getLocation().setYaw(yaw);

        AbstractHorse horse = (AbstractHorse) event.getRightClicked();
        player.sendMessage(horse.getName());
    }
}
```

and also similarly tried saving the player's direction (via `player.getLocation().getDirection()`) then setting it again after cancelling the event, to no avail. Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found that you can't actually directly edit a player's pitch and yaw. You have to teleport the player to a custom Location with the custom pitch and yaw values, like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractEntity (PlayerInteractEntityEvent event) {
    Entity entity = event.getRightClicked();
    Player player = event.getPlayer();

    float pitch = player.getLocation().getPitch();
    float yaw = player.getLocation().getYaw();

    if (entity instanceof AbstractHorse) {
        event.setCancelled(true);

        Location loc = player.getLocation();
        loc.setPitch(pitch);
        loc.setYaw(yaw);
        player.teleport(loc);

        AbstractHorse horse = (AbstractHorse) event.getRightClicked();
        player.sendMessage(horse.getName());
    }
}
```

So now the player would still be looking to where they were looking at before right-clicking a horse, although it looks glitchy. There's no other way to do it so far, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `entity` in your if-condition, but you never declare it. Use this code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractEntity (PlayerInteractEntityEvent event) {
    Entity entity = event.getRightClicked();

    if (entity instanceof AbstractHorse) {
        event.setCancelled(true);

        AbstractHorse horse = (AbstractHorse) entity;
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        player.sendMessage(horse.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is true, it's not the issue. Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `VehicleEnterEvent`. It's the event that's thrown when an Entity starts riding another Entity (it includes horses, minecarts, or any other entity under the right circumstance).

It's defined in the [spigot javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325846/spigot-playerinteractentityevent)

---

Quick example on how to implement it:

```
@EventHandler
public void onHorseMount(VehicleEnterEvent e) {
    Entity entered = e.getEntered();
    Vehicle enteredOn = e.getVehicle();
    if (enteredOn instanceof AbstractHorse) {

        //Entity entered a Horse

        if (!(entered instanceof Player))return; //Returns if this is not a player

        Player mountingHorse = (Player) entered;
        AbstractHorse horseEntered = (AbstractHorse) enteredOn;
        mountingHorse.sendMessage(horseEntered.getName());   //Sending the message
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use `player.getEyeLocation()` to retrieve pitch and yaw values

Comment: Doesn't help OP's issue